# Uninterrupted nginx + 2 gunicorns setup

Tags: python, nginx, gunicorn

So what's the trick? Nginx is facing the client. Normally the requests are forwarded to gunicorn A at port 80.

[image: nginx/two gunicorn setup]

You can't run code update in-place, since something might be wrong. So you do a fresh code checkout and launch a separate gunicorn B on some port 5678.

Once you test the new code on a development/testing database, you:

- Adjust gunicorn B to point to the database, but do not send any requests.
- Stop gunicorn A. Nginx now, ever so briefly, responds with an error.
- Set nginx to point to gunicorn B, still at port 5678.
- Restart nginx.

Is this about right? Do you just write a script to run the four actions faster and minimize the duration (between steps 2 and 4) the server responds with an error?

Comment: I would suggest see this https://wingu.github.io/zero-downtime-gunicorn.html

Comment: @TarunLalwani Interesting. That spawns two quick True-False questions: 1- "There exists a solution to this problem that not just drops the server-down duration from 1-2 milliseconds to zero." and (given your clear expertise) 2- "When one is ready to move to Docker, Docker will provide a solution to this issue." If you're able to comment T/F for one or both, until I know how to formulate a clearer question, please do.

Comment: 1. yes, lot of different approaches exists for this. 2. Docker, in case of Docker Swarm or Kubernetes you have zero downtime deployments, we use the same with kubernetes in our case

Comment: You can try using pm2 like module. I’m not quite sure in it works well with python though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx supports [configuration reloading](https://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html). Using this feature, updating your application can work like this:

1. Start a new instance Gunicorn B.
2. Adjust the nginx configuration to forward traffic to Gunicorn B.
3. Reload the nginx configuration with `nginx -s reload`. After this, Gunicorn B will serve new requests, while Gunicorn A will still finish serving old requests.
4. Wait for the old nginx worker process to exit (which means all requests initiated before the reload are now done) and then stop Gunicorn A.

Assuming your application works correctly with two concurrent instances, this gives you a zero-downtime update.

The relevant excerpt from the nginx documentation:

> Once the master process receives the signal to reload configuration, it checks the syntax validity of the new configuration file and tries to apply the configuration provided in it. If this is a success, the master process starts new worker processes and sends messages to old worker processes, requesting them to shut down. Otherwise, the master process rolls back the changes and continues to work with the old configuration. Old worker processes, receiving a command to shut down, stop accepting new connections and continue to service current requests until all such requests are serviced. After that, the old worker processes exit.